# Is it possible to get data storage details of a Salesforce organization using Apex code

Tags: data, file-storage, data-storage

I am trying to get details of space used by several sObjects, Attachment and other using Apex code. I can get Attachments details but is there any possibility to get how much data has been consumed by an sObject e.g; Case, Lead etc..

In my opinion this may not possible. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it a requirement to get the data through apex,if not it is readily available for you at setup-->company profile search for used data space and click view next to it

Comment: Yes, I need to get data details through apex @rao

Comment: Related: [Can we query the info from “Data Management -> Storage Usage” through SOAP API?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/9474/102)

Answer (score 4):

This has been made possible by now via the `OrgLimits` class [1].

```java
Map<String,System.OrgLimit> limitsMap = OrgLimits.getMap();
System.OrgLimit fileStorage = limitsMap.get('FileStorageMB');
System.debug('Limit Name: ' + fileStorage.getName());
System.debug('Usage Value: ' + fileStorage.getValue());
System.debug('Maximum Limit: ' + fileStorage.getLimit());
```

You seem to be able to use the limit descriptors that are available via the REST API's limits resource [2].

[1] https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_OrgLimits.htm
[2] https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for this currently, either Apex or otherwise, one could envision it one day being part of the Metadata API (or Tooling API?) perhaps, but currently not. The only programatic way to do this would be to screen scrape the information from the Data Storage page yourself in Apex code. Its far from ideal but could be done if you are happy with the risks (e.g. the HTML changing in future platform releases or fixes and you have to tweak your parsing logic). Here is a post from Metadaddy describing the process and the warnings... [screen scrape Salesforce with REST GET call from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/screen-scrape-salesforce-with-rest-get-call-from-apex)