# How to find current storage limit usage in Salesforce (in tests)?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

We have [Limits class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) and lot of methods showing current usage of DML statements, SOQL queries etc, but there is no method which shows total amount of storage capacity for records and no method which shows current usage of storage for records?
Is that true or am I missing anything?

Created [an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Lez4AAC) on Idea Exchange, please vote if you find it necessary and must have.

Comment: tl;dr - not directly available, screen scrape. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18165/is-it-possible-to-get-data-storage-details-of-a-salesforce-organization-using-ap

Comment: @BrianMansfield Is it possible to screen scrape from unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any Apex methods for finding total storage. Because as per my knowledge, that is way beyond Apex's pay grade.

Apex can find limits within the context it is running in such as available heap, available queries, callouts etc.

But things like overall org storage, number of remaining user licenses, test percentage, total code in the org etc are not possible, and in most cases might not be made possible in the future as well.

Comment: As far as I know at least Overall code coverage and coverage for given class \ given method I can access programatically, I would love to receive everything else in similar way