# how to get sfdc space utilization via SOAP API?

Tags: soap-api, webservices, integration

In my requirement, i need to get SFDC space utilization and display data into third-part systems. But, after i searching SOAP API, I  didn't found any api description about space utilization. guys, if you know it about this api, would you please let know.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such API. Lots of people are asking about it but the only solution for now is a workaround. It's very fragile solution because it's just... screen scrapping of Data Management -> Storage Usage page, see the response for similar question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9474/can-we-query-the-info-from-data-management-storage-usage-through-soap-api)