# Why does 18-character ID casing matter in a SOQL WHERE clause?

Tags: soql

When an ID value is upper-case the expected rows are returned in a SOQL query. However, when using a lower-case ID in the where clause, zero rows are returned.

It also doesn't matter if it's a `String` or an `Id` type.

Is this a change to SQOL where clause behavior? I would expect it to work no matter the case of the string... after all, **what's the point of case-insensitivity if you've got to make sure it's in the proper case before you execute the query**?

**Update** further investigation has revealed that the behavior is different per object. In the two examples, Account and User queries behave differently. Accounts don't work at all but Users do when the Id is upper-case.

### User

**Exec Anon - User**

```
String upperId = '005L0000001JVZUIA4';
List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: upperId];
system.debug(users);

String lowerId = '005L0000001JVZUIA4'.toLowerCase();
List<User> users2 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: lowerId];
system.debug(users2);

Id idFromUpper = (Id)upperId;
List<User> users3 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: idFromUpper];
system.debug(users3);

Id idFromLower = (Id)lowerId;
List<User> users4 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: idFromLower];
system.debug(users4);
```

**Result - User**

```
EXECUTION_STARTED
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[2]|Aggregations:0|select Id from User where Id = :tmpVar1
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[2]|Rows:1
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[3]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|(User:{Id=005L0000001JVZUIA4})
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[3]|System.debug(ANY)

SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|String.toLowerCase()
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|String.toLowerCase()
SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[6]|Aggregations:0|select Id from User where Id = :tmpVar1
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[6]|Rows:0
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[7]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|()
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[7]|System.debug(ANY)

SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[10]|Aggregations:0|select Id from User where Id = :tmpVar1
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[10]|Rows:1
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[11]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|(User:{Id=005L0000001JVZUIA4})
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[11]|System.debug(ANY)

SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[14]|Aggregations:0|select Id from User where Id = :tmpVar1
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[14]|Rows:0
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[15]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[15]|DEBUG|()
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[15]|System.debug(ANY)

CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 4 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 2 out of 50000
```

### Account

**Exec Anon - Account**

```
List<Account> a = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
system.debug(a);

String upperId = '001E000000WTEqoIAH'.toUpperCase();
system.debug('Upper: ' + upperId);
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id =: upperId];
system.debug('Accounts: ' + accounts);

String lowerId = '001E000000WTEqoIAH'.toLowerCase();
system.debug('Lower: ' + lowerId);
List<Account> accounts2 = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id =: lowerId];
system.debug('Accounts 2:' + accounts2);
```

**Result - Account**

```
EXECUTION_STARTED
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[1]|Aggregations:0|select Id from Account limit 1
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[1]|Rows:1
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[2]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|(Account:{Id=001E000000WTEqoIAH}) // curiously, it's an 18-character in mixed case
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[2]|System.debug(ANY)

SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[4]|String.toUpperCase()
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[4]|String.toUpperCase()
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|Upper: 001E000000WTEQOIAH
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|System.debug(ANY)

SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[6]|Aggregations:0|select Id from Account where Id = :tmpVar1
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[6]|Rows:0
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[7]|String.valueOf(Object)
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[7]|String.valueOf(Object)
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[7]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|Accounts: ()
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[7]|System.debug(ANY)

SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|String.toLowerCase()
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[9]|String.toLowerCase()
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[10]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|Lower: 001e000000wteqoiah
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[10]|System.debug(ANY)

SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[11]|Aggregations:0|select Id from Account where Id = :tmpVar1
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[11]|Rows:0
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[12]|String.valueOf(Object)
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[12]|String.valueOf(Object)
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[12]|System.debug(ANY)
USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|Accounts 2:()
SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[12]|System.debug(ANY)

CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 1 out of 50000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting this here just so that anyone else who comes along and missed the spectacular shining gem dropped by Peter Chittum in another question.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9570/660

> The "case-insensitive" Id is not case-insensitive in and of itself. It
>   is **unique case-insensitive**.
>
> Could SFDC convert the id using the reverse of the algorithm derived
>   from the last 3 digits of the 18? Yes. But we don't. Not being the
>   person who designed or built them, but just another developer in the
>   field like you, near as I can tell we just drop those characters,
>   meaning if you have code that manipulates any of the alpha characters
>   and changes their case, you will have broken the Id.

I'm so happy to have come across this. Thanks Peter!

Comment: If you do want to resurrect the correct ID casing from the suffix see [Creating a link using an 18 character ID](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9569/102).

Answer (score 1):

Reason behind this is the ID checksum. ID is combination of Record Unique Identifier + Checksum calculated of Record Unique Identifier.

Ids are **case sensitive**. And their checksum must not be changed during transaction.

In you case you have Id in upper case. I do have `00590000001LjyRAAS`.

So Query against your logic only third will work only.

```
// It doesn't work
String uppercaseId = '00590000001LjyRAAS'.toUpperCase();
List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: uppercaseId];
system.debug(users);

// It doesn't work
String lowerId = '00590000001LjyRAAS'.toLowerCase();
List<User> users2 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: lowerId];
system.debug(users2);

// It works
String actualId = '00590000001LjyRAAS';
List<User> users3 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: actualId];
system.debug(users3);
```

In browser:

```
// It does not work (character Y is capital)
https://huddle-idp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/00590000001LjYR?noredirect=1

// It works
https://huddle-idp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/00590000001LjyR?noredirect=1
```

All character cases (including check sum if SOQL) must match to get expected result.

Comment: This answer doesn't make logical sense. The whole reason for the 3 checksum characters is so that the ID can be represented in a case-insensitive manner where the checksum characters can be used to determine the case sensitive representation. If the casing must match on all 18 characters, that completely defeats the purpose.

Comment: @MarkPond But it doesn't work. Few people face this problem as most of the logic is automated and no one manipulate Ids during execution.

Comment: So, given an 18 character ID that is in lower-case (for any reason) what's your suggested approach to being able to query for that record?

Comment: @MarkPond Earlier case insensitive IDs were introduced to make VLookup work and make it easy to export data into excel. As well in formulas functions case sensitive IDs were causing various issues. So Salesforce made Ids case insensitive for those scenarios and changes logic to return 18 character Id in all scenarios. But it doesn't work in Apex mode.

Comment: Your examples demonstrate that only the first 15 characters of the Id string are considered by by the SOQL query and because of that, it's case-sensitive. That's interesting.