# Converting uppercased 18-digit Id to valid Id

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

I am currently facing an issue where an external system passes back an 18-digit Id that our platform has previously sent to them. However in the process the capitalization of the Id has been removed - read everything has become uppercase. I would imagine somebody has faced this problem before, but apparantly this is not the case.

So in short; is somebody aware of any existing (apex-) function that converts uppercased 18-digit Ids to a valid Salesforce Id?

Please beware; while a lot of answers exist for converting 15 to 18 digits, which is trivial, this is a different problem.

Comment: I don't think that conversion you are asking is possible. As a solution you can use a `Map<String, sObjectt>` having String as 18-digit Id in uppercase.

Comment: You might find your answer here: [Creating a link using an 18 character ID](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9568/creating-a-link-using-an-18-character-id)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ported [Daniel Ballinger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger)'s answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9568/creating-a-link-using-an-18-character-id/9569#9569) to `Apex`:

```
static String CHARS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345';

static List<Boolean> getBitPattern(String c)
{
    Integer index = CHARS.indexOf(c.toUpperCase());
    List<Boolean> result = new List<Boolean>();
    for (Integer bitNumber = 0; bitNumber < 5; bitNumber++)
        result.add((index & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0);
    return result;
}
static String repairCasing(String input)
{
    if (String.isBlank(input) || input.length() != 18) return input;

    List<Boolean> toUpper = new List<Boolean>();
    toUpper.addAll(getBitPattern(String.valueOf(input.substring(15, 16))));
    toUpper.addAll(getBitPattern(String.valueOf(input.substring(16, 17))));
    toUpper.addAll(getBitPattern(String.valueOf(input.substring(17, 18))));

    String output = '';
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        String c = String.valueOf(input.substring(i, i+1));
        output += toUpper[i] ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase();
    }
    output += input.substring(15, 18).toUpperCase();
    return output;
}
```

I tested it and it worked:

```
Id value1 = Id.valueOf('00129000007Kbn7AAC');
Id value2 = Id.valueOf('00129000007KBN7AAC');

system.assertEquals(value1, repairCasing(value2));
```

Comment: can you explain how `toUpper[i] ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase()` works? I'm trying to recreate this in python now and I'm not familiar with that syntax

Comment: @Jwok That seems like a great question to post. Specifically, you would likely get good responses to a post asking how to convert this algorithm to Python. Especially if you can post what you have already done to try to convert, and where specifically you are stuck. Please use the **[Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)** link to pose it to the broader community.

Comment: FYI it's **ternary** syntax. In Python you'd use `c.upper() if toUpper[i] else c.lower()`.

Comment: got it figured out and posted it to this thread. I also created a new post on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564084/how-to-fix-a-capitalized-salesforce-18-digit-id) for a signal boost

Comment: There's a typo on line 16 - should be `input.substring(15, 16)`. This won't matter for _most_ Ids (as most start with numbers) but any Ids that start with letters will have all those letters made lowercase.

Comment: Interesting. It did work before. I'll have to test it out before I update the post content.

Comment: The code did not work for me. I implemented @YodaDaCoda suggestion and it worked, so I've updated the post.

Answer (score 10):

Parallel to Adrian's response I also cooked up my own version for reference;

```
public static Id correctCapitalizedId(String input) {
    String keyString = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345', result = '';
    Integer i = 0, s = 15;

    if (input.length() != 18) {
        return null;
    }

    for (String seq : input.split('(?<=\\G.{5})')) {
        Integer chk = keyString.indexOf(input.mid(s++,1));
        i = 0;
        for (String chr : seq.split('')) {
            result += seq.length() != 5  ? '' : (chk & (i == 0 ? ++i : (i*=2))) == 0 ? chr.toLowerCase() : chr;
        }
    }
    return Id.valueOf(result);
}
```

Comment: Elegant. Way to take the cleanup a step further!

Comment: Had to edit my code slightly - it was not working correctly in the sense that the last 3 characters were always lowercased - this causes Id.valueOf to render an Id - but subsequently actually using this Id while trying to populate/commit a lookup-field will still render a nasty error....

Comment: This fails if any part of the 3 character checksum is lowercase.  Adding `input = input.toUpperCase()` at the top of the function fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but new apex specific solution: As of version 54.0 you can simple use Id.valueOf(str, restoreCasing), see here for more information:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_id_valueOf_2

Answer (score 1):

Given that the 18 character form of an ID is designed to be a unique identifier irrespective of the casing, I'm not sure why you would ever need to convert to a 15 digit ID.

Why not stay with the 18 character values? If you did for example need to use them as string map keys just normalise their case by using `toLowerCase()` on them. They remain valid ID values and can be converted to the type [Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm) using `Id.valueOf`.

Comment: You cannot query on it or view the detail page via url if the casing is incorrect. Try it in the dev console. Worth taking a look at the post I flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Also worth noting the OP does not want to go from 18 to 15, just to fix the casing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Fix to use in the URL or are there other contexts where there is case sensitivity?

Comment: Hard to say *why*. The two most obvious cases I've seen are in any url or query. It would also affect comparison, but it's hard to see how that would come into play.

Comment: Purpose here was actually querying for the record indeed!

Comment: @KoenFaro Maybe my misunderstanding - I though the query will work whatever the casing of the 18 characters, kinda the whole point.

Comment: Thats what I assumed too @KeithC, until I noticed that my test-case only had uppercase characters to start with and things broke down in production!

Comment: @KoenFaro OK I did a bit more reading and I get it now. Correctly cased 18 chars or 15 chars work in queries but if case is lost code needs running to use the extra info in the extra 3 character os the 18 chars to recover the correct casing of the 15 chars. Seems like a method that should be present on the Id class but isn't.

Comment: I would actually expect it to be part of the native Id.valueOf function, rather strange that SF skipped implementing the few lines of code above, sounds like  a rush job of adding 18 character Ids - if you open the idea I'll vote!

Comment: @KoenFaro If I believed opening developer-oriented ideas made any difference I would...

Comment: [Open](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Lky3QAC). Though I agree it's probably moot.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Voted for by me.

Comment: Peter Chittum provided some insight to me a while ago on this very point - casing _does_ matter, always. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/50483/660

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is using it, I took Adrian Larson's apex code and converted it to Python.

```
def getBitPatterns(c):
    CHARS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345'
    index = CHARS.find(c)
    result = []
    for bitNumber in range(0,5):
        result.append((index & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0)
    return result

def repairCasing(inp):
    if len(inp) < 18:
        return 'Error'
    toUpper = []
    toUpper.append(getBitPatterns(inp[15:16]))
    toUpper.append(getBitPatterns(inp[16:17]))
    toUpper.append(getBitPatterns(inp[17:18]))
    toUpper = [item for sublist in toUpper for item in sublist]

    output = ''

    for i in range(0,15):
        c = inp[i:i+1]
        if toUpper[i]:
            output += c.upper()
        else:
            output += c.lower()

    output += inp[15:18].upper()

    return output
```

Comment: I think you can get the last 12 lines down to one with a list comprehension if you like. `return ''.join([x.upper() if x in toUpper else x.lower() for x in inp[:15]] + inp[15:].upper()`

Comment: I messed it up, of course. `in toUpper` should just be `toUpper[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs to do this with PHP, I ported Adrian's answer. Requires PHP 8.0 or newer:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Shadowhand\Salesforce;

use function assert;
use function strlen;
use function strpos;
use function strtolower;
use function strtoupper;
use function substr;

/**
 * @link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123217/converting-uppercased-18-digit-id-to-valid-id
 */
final class SalesforceId
{
    private const CHARS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345';

    public static function correct(string $input): string
    {
        assert(assertion: strlen($input) === 18);

        $id = '';

        $capitalize = [
            ...self::shouldCapitalize(letter: substr($input, offset: 15, length: 1)),
            ...self::shouldCapitalize(letter: substr($input, offset: 16, length: 1)),
            ...self::shouldCapitalize(letter: substr($input, offset: 17, length: 1)),
        ];

        for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
            $letter = substr($input, offset: $i, length: 1);

            $id .= $capitalize[$i] ? strtoupper($letter) : strtolower($letter);
        }

        $id .= strtoupper(substr($input, offset: 15, length: 3));

        return $id;
    }

    private static function shouldCapitalize(string $letter): array
    {
        $index = strpos(haystack: self::CHARS, needle: strtoupper($letter));
        $result = [];

        for ($bit = 0; $bit < 5; $bit++) {
            $result[] = ($index & (1 << $bit)) !== 0;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

And here is the PHPUnit test:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Shadowhand\Salesforce;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

use function strtolower;
use function strtoupper;

class SalesforceIdTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testShouldCorrectCapitalization(): void
    {
        $id = '00129000007Kbn7AAC';

        self::assertSame(expected: $id, actual: SalesforceId::correct(strtoupper($id)));
        self::assertSame(expected: $id, actual: SalesforceId::correct(strtolower($id)));
    }
}
```