# Retrieving All Accounts in a Hierarchy Using 15-Character ID

Tags: soql

I have an Account hierarchy. I have a formula on my Account that returns the ID of the Account at the top of the hierarchy. Due to formula size restraints, I can't use `CASESAFEID` in the formula, so it only returns the 15 character ID. Return type of the formula is Text (String).

My use case is given one Account, return all the Accounts in its hierarchy. The problem is, I have a 15 character ID from the formula and SOQL is not case sensitive.

So if I do something like this:

```
Account a = [SELECT Id, Ultimate_Parent_Id__c FROM Account LIMIT 1];
String parentId = a.Ultimate_Parent_Id__c;
String query = 'SELECT Id, ' + Util.GetDynamicQueryString() + ' FROM Account WHERE Ultimate_Parent_Id__c =: parentId';
List<Account> results = Database.query(query);
```

This won't work because theoretically there could be multiple Accounts with that 15-character ID when it is processed case-insensitive.

Since SOQL can't compare the String values in a case sensitive manner, the only way I can think to do this is to write a trigger to stamp the 18 character ID of the ultimate parent on create or reparent.

Has anyone figured out a way around this?

Comment: I'd have to see your formula, but I suspect there'd be a way to optimize it to fit the casesafeid formula in.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Formula is as follows. It's ugly as sin, but it works for the most part and our hierarchies are not more than 5 deep.   `IF(isblank(Parent.Id),Id,
IF(isblank(Parent.Parent.Id),Parent.Id,
IF(isblank(Parent.Parent.Parent.Id),Parent.Parent.Id,
IF(isblank(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id),Parent.Parent.Parent.Id,
IF(isblank(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id),Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id,
IF(isblank(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id),Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id,
null
))))))`

Comment: So, I was wrong, I tried creating a casesafeid version using the best optimization I could think of: `casesafeid(BLANKVALUE(
Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId,
BLANKVALUE(
Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId,
BLANKVALUE(
Parent.Parent.ParentId,
BLANKVALUE(
Parent.ParentId,
ParentId)))))` ... it was still too long about about 3k characters. You'll probably want to make a Process Builder to avoid using a trigger to populate the data.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you!

Comment: I think I'm missing something - so long as you aren't _destroying_ the case of the characters in a 15-character Id, it's perfectly valid for use in any Salesforce API. SOQL on case-preserved 15 character Ids works fine. Are your Ids clamped to upper or lower case?

Comment: David, the problem is that the formula returns a String, so it's a String comparison, not ID to ID.

Comment: According to the answers here, soql will automatically cast the string to ID for ID field comparisons, so you should be able to use your formula field: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18088/soql-where-clause-use-15-character-id

Comment: David C., Thank you for the suggestions. The implication of your link is that in my snippet above, in the 2nd line, if I cast the String to an Id instead it will be processed in SOQL as an Id comparison since only one of the two things being compared needs to be an Id.  I'll need to test this. Thank you for the information.

Comment: FWIW, system will NOT auto-cast String to ID when ONE of the things being compared in the SOQL statement is an ID. A quick test in Exec Anon: in our system `ultimate_parent_id__c`is the formula that returns 15-digit ID as text:
`Id ultimateParent = '0014100001Vxxxx';

system.debug([select id from account where ultimate_parent_id__c =: ultimateparent]);` --> returns NO results.

`String ultimateParentStr = '0014100001Vxxxx';

system.debug([select id from account where ultimate_parent_id__c =: ultimateparentStr]);` DOES.

I think I need to carry the 18-char ID and set w/trigger.