# Explaination of URL

Tags: login

Can anybody explain the url.
- https://ap1.salesforce.com/hexcode

I wanted to know that when i hit this url, what is the first thing it do/search or anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hexcode string is in id format ('0039000001Czs88') then it shows the record that has that id.
Otherwise it will return no url page.

If 'apex/ hexcode' is in the url then it search for apex page that has name as 'hexcode' other wise it will show a visualforce error that 'Page hexcode does not exist '

Comment: Thanks Monish, here i'm more concern to functional flow.
Let me clear the scenarios -
i have created a site with suppose url 'https://dildar1987.na17.visual.force.com/apex/page' when i hit the url it will show me the site loggin page. after login i'll get loggedout and hit the url 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/0039000001Czs88' now after hitting the url it is redirecting me to site login page but i want it to redirect to salesforce login page.

Comment: Sorry am not getting it. Site login page means have you enabled community ??

Comment: can u post your orgs url?

Comment: Hi Monish,
Please consider the below scenario to have more understanding -
1. created a site page of my org. and mentioned a custom visualforce page for login.
2. When i login from above page and get outof it(logout) its redirecting me to same custom login page.

now its an expected behavior but after logout when i enter URL - https://ap1.salesforce.com/0039000001Czs88 its again redirect me to the custom login page.

Comment: But its should redirect to the standard salesforce login page.

Comment: you mean you are getting redirected to site custom login page than the login.salesforce.com which is the login page for you org right ????

Comment: I was planning to setup my dev org to test, but it is an older one without the portal licenses.  I suspect there is a cookie causing this.  I know there is one for the internal users to login, I'd imagine they extended it to the external logins as well.  If you have your site setup, check to see if any new cookies show up after logging into the external site.

Answer (score 1):

The code at the end is an object ID, not a hex code.  It is simply alphanumeric ID of 15 characters that is sometimes seen with 18 characters, the last 3 being used for a checksum on non-case sensitive systems accessing the API (IDs are case sensitive).

The first 3 represent the SObject prefix.  You'll commonly see things like .../500/e (500 prefix is Case object) which allows you to create a new SObject of that type.  Likewise the prefix with no ending /e would bring up a list view of the SObject type (e.g. .../500).

There is another post on the exchange that contains a bit more than you asked for that might be worth checking out:

[What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of)

Comment: Thanks drakored, here i'm more concern to functional flow.
Let me clear the scenarios -
i have created a site with suppose url 'https://dildar1987.na17.visual.force.com/apex/page' when i hit the url it will show me the site loggin page. after login i'll get loggedout and hit the url 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/0039000001Czs88' now after hitting the url it is redirecting me to site login page but i want it to redirect to salesforce login page.