# Salesforce SOQL:Why it return different ID value when I use different Id?

Tags: apex, soql

I  run this query :

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM  Account where Id='0013000000Ghg4k'
```

it returns the value but I noticed the different of return Id.Query with '**0013000000Ghg4k**' and it return Id '**0013000000Ghg4kAAB**' It is not same except some beginning character but how it able to return the value at the first place?Any explaination on this.

[image: Note that different Id while I expect it to be same]

Comment: check out the article here:  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-do-unique-IDs-work-in-Salesforce-1327108651310&language=en_US

Comment: If  user give me 15 characters id in Set, then I query with it  and store return  data inside map which 18 character as key, my map won't be searchable except if I truncate the return Id from query then store as map key.I wonder is there easy method to solve this type of issue.

Comment: Id comparison is different from string comparison. So that should not be a problem at all. A 15 char Id will be equal to its 18 char counterpart in comparison.

Comment: So instead using map<String,Account> mapAccount, it is better to use <Id,Account> ?

Comment: yes, always....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. 15 digit case-sensitive version which is referenced in the UI
2. 18 digit case-insensitive version which is referenced through the API

The last 3 digits of the 18 digit ID are a checksum of the capitalisations of the first 15 characters, this ID length was created as a workaround to legacy systems which were not compatible with case-sensitive IDs.
The API will accept the 15 digit ID as input but will always return the 18 digit ID.

Here is a great answer [What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of) if you want to know how the Id is composed.