# How to get an 18 digit ID from 15 digit ID using SOQL

Tags: soql, salesforce-id

I have a 15 digit Sfdc ID, but I do not know which object it belongs to.

How can I find out which objects it belongs to and the convert it to 18 digits - all using SOQL?

**P.S.**  I was annoyed at having to do this manually every single time, so I created a small app that detects 15 digits SFDC IDs and then automatically up converts them to 18 digits.

Video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xwd9WkcG10

Github: https://github.com/rgelb/SfdcIdUpConverter

Download: https://github.com/rgelb/SfdcIdUpConverter/releases/download/1.2/SfdcIdUpConverterSetup.exe

P.S. The code no longer works with the latest rev of Salesforce.  I am not planning to make any updates as I no longer work with Salesforce.  If anyone wants to fork the GitHub repo, it might live on.

Comment: You can directly query the id of an sObject using the 15 char id value, and get the 18 char value returned. `[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = '006V000000NT4kj']` will return the value `'006V000000NT4kjIOU'`.

Comment: Have a read of [What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1653). The 15 and 18 character ID's can be used interchangeably in SOQL.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To convert it to 18 digits you can simply set it to an `Id` type variable:

```
Id someId = '001J000001eun1Q';
```

Which will automatically convert it for you:

```
system.debug(someId); // 001J000001eun1QIAQ
```

Then you can simply call the `getSObjectType()` method on the Id variable which will return the object name:

```
Schema.SObjectType objectType = someId.getSObjectType();
system.debug(objectType); // Account
```

Comment: But thats nit soql :)

Comment: You can't do that using SOQL, you have to use APEX.

Comment: That's also correct

Comment: Didn't get the answer I would have liked...but just the system.debug trick is worth millions!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but just in case it is useful to someone, if you want to do ad-hoc conversions of Id's, rather than programatically, then this Chrome extension makes it easy:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sf-15-to-18/cogllpmaoflgaekieefhmglbpgdgmoeg

FYI - I'm the developer. Please use the feedback form on the app if you'd like to suggest any improvements or additional functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Your extension works perfectly. I would like to understand the logic behind conversion of 15 digit to 18 digit. We need to build this conversion process in a c# application

Comment: This page explains it quite well: https://www.gammone.com/en/programming/how-to-convert-salesforce-id-from-15-to-18-chars