# Create Case thread Id using Apex (SOQL limit-proof)

Tags: apex, governorlimits

There are many posts about creating Case threadIds with Apex, notably [Case.Thread_Id, is Thread_Id a field on Case object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103254/case-thread-id-is-thread-id-a-field-on-case-object)

As the posters have noted, the SFDC rules of the threadId are subject to change over time and the only reliable way that I've seen is to do [this:](http:////%20To%20be%20replaced%20with%20a%20real%20case%20Id.%20Id%20caseId%20=%20'500c0000008kJL5';%20%20%20List%3CMessaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult%3E%20renderResults%20=%20Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(null,%20caseId,%20new%20List%3CString%3E%7B'%7B!Case.Thread_Id%7D'%7D);%20%20System.debug('this%20is%20the%20Case%20Thread%20Id:%20'%20+%20renderResults[0].getMergedBody());)

```
// To be replaced with a real case Id.
Id caseId = '500c0000008kJL5'; 

List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult> renderResults =
  Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(null, caseId, new List<String>{'{!Case.Thread_Id}'});

System.debug('this is the Case Thread Id: ' + renderResults[0].getMergedBody());
```

**HOWEVER ...**
The method call `Messaging.renderEmailTemplate` burns a SOQL ([see doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm))

So you can't prepopulate your Cases in an afterInsert or beforeUpdate Trigger because a transaction can be up to 2,000 (Platform Events), up to 10,000 (direct Apex DML) or more, typically, 200 rows.  All of these are > 100 SOQL limit.

> So, before I go to the trouble of doing this in a chained set of async
>   tasks; is there more recent thinking on this subject of creating ThreadIds?

Comment: It is worth noting that once [Critical Update Disable Ref ID and Transition to New Email Threading Behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000355168) is enabled, the `Messaging.renderEmailTemplate` no longer generates a threadID.

Comment: same comment is true when enabling Release Update [Disable Ref ID and Switch to Lightning Threading](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389648&type=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, if you need this, you'll have to go asynchronous. Queueable would probably be best, but that's up to your discretion. There's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XvdHAAS) to enable a field that could be used, and presumably that could solve the problem at a more fundamental level, so you might want to vote on it.

Comment: yes -- a difficult issue as one wants the threadId for use in VF email templates based on deltas in Case; so PBs and WFR need to be gated by presence of threadId before executing and async Txn, even with soql limit of 200 can't consume all 200 doing `renderEmailTemplate` as that leaves no headroom for soqls done by the aforementioned WFR/PBs. Tuning for the right "batch size" in the async txn is "guessing/leaving enough headroom and hoping for the best". Your remark `if you need this...` is spot-on

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working perfectly....:)

I am sending out email from Apex by passing case id and using template.

I've replaced thread_id from html body with the new formula string, and on case I can see all reply's getting captured in same thread.

```
/*Configuring thread ID*/

String caseId = cri.CaseId;

Case_ThreadID = 'ref:!' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId().left(5)  + '0' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId().mid(11,4) + '.!'  + caseId.left(5) + '0' + caseId.mid(10,5)+':ref';

 
//replacing template threadid from HTML body//

if(htmlBody.contains('{!Case.Thread_Id}')){

    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Case.Thread_Id}', Case_ThreadID);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a great answer for this question because it assumes what the format of the thread id is, and as OP stated, `As the posters have noted, the SFDC rules of the threadId are subject to change over time`.