# How to put the Thread ID in Apex sent mail?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I managed to create a Rest Apex Class that sends an emailmessage, attached to a given case.
But unfortunately, the sent email lacks  the tag ref:_00D3X2nqVQ._5003X1tjFN0:ref

I guess that's because I need to set a Thread Id, but I don't know how to do it

Manually created / sent eMailMessge do get the ref:_00D3X2nqVQ._5003X1tjFN0:ref appended to the body

Comment: Manually create emailcase threadId?
https://thysmichels.com/2018/02/09/generating-an-email-to-case-thread-id-using-apex/

Comment: I need to automate this

Comment: How do you send email Apex Email?

Comment: I created an Apex Class

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237194/create-case-thread-id-using-apex-soql-limit-proof

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field for Case thread Id with formula as below:

```
"ref:_" &
LEFT( $Organization.Id , 5) &
IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 6, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id,10),
IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 7, 1) <> "0",RIGHT($Organization.Id, 9),
IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 8, 1) <>"0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 8),
IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 9, 1)<> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 7),
IF (MID ( $Organization.Id,10, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 6),
IF (MID ($Organization.Id, 11, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 5),
IF(MID ( $Organization.Id, 12, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id,4),
IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 13, 1) <> "0",RIGHT($Organization.Id, 3),
IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 14, 1) <>"0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 2), "") ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
& "._" &LEFT( Id, 5) &
IF(MID ( Id, 6, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 10),
IF (MID ( Id, 7, 1)<> "0", RIGHT(Id, 9),
IF (MID ( Id, 8, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id,8),
IF (MID ( Id, 9, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 7),
IF (MID ( Id, 10,1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 6),
IF (MID ( Id, 11, 1) <> "0",RIGHT(Id, 5),
IF (MID ( Id, 12, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 4),
IF (MID( Id, 13, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 3),
IF (MID ( Id, 14, 1) <>"0", RIGHT(Id, 2), "") ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) & ":ref"
```

Then append this formula field in the subject line or email body in your apex class if you are generating them in the class. If you are using an email template, you can append the field directly in the email template using merged fields.

Hope this helps.

Comment: looks great the standalone "Id", is that the case id ?

Comment: Yes. The field needs to be created on Case object.

Comment: these formula fields are known to be fragile - see other posts on this topic - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237194/create-case-thread-id-using-apex-soql-limit-proof

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work for me. In the link you pointed me, someone said it burns a sooql, do you know which would be the query