# System.InvalidParameterValueException: You don't have access to the getCaseIdFromEmailThreadId apex method. Use getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders instead

Tags: email2case

Spring 25 sees a Release Update enforcement of the latest Email-to-Case threading mechanism [Disable RefId and Switch to Lightning Threading](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389648&type=1)

- I have an org that is still using RefId threading
- I want to ensure that once I switch to Lightning Threading, that incoming emails containing the old RefId thread token will still match to the Case in the event that Lightning Threading Token fallback strategy (header-based threading) fails.
- Given that my code can inspect the incoming email and detect the RefId threadId (e.g. `ref:!00DXXXXXXX.!5000XXXXXXX:ref` )

  - I can use the (deprecated) method to find the caseId `Id caseId = Cases.getCaseIdFromEmailThreadId(refId)`

However, when I use this, I get the error:

```
System.InvalidParameterValueException: You don't have access to the getCaseIdFromEmailThreadId apex method. 
Use getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders instead.
```

I tried with Apex class versions 46 - 60; same error. How do I resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error ensues as soon as you enable the Release Update [Disable RefId and Switch to Lightning Threading](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389648&type=1).

- If you disable the Release Update, the method works fine

Although the error states use `getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders` instead, this doesn't apply to my use case as I know that some incoming emails have the SFDC headers stripped off by our secure messaging platform.

So, for my org at least, before I turn on the Release Update, I will ensure that every Case is updated using a custom field `Case.RefId_Token__c` with the RefId. There are different approaches to get this:

- From the actual EmailMessage sent from a Case using Regex.
- Using the October 2023 formula as outlined in this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeF6UAJ/case-thread-id-as-field-on-case-page-layout) - possibly fragile as refId format has changed over time
- Using a [non-bulkified method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237194/create-case-thread-id-using-apex-soql-limit-proof)

  ```
    List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult> renderResults =
          Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(null, caseId, new List<String>{'{!Case.Thread_Id}'});
  ```

Then, any inbound email that creates a new Case that contains a RefId can be matched against existing cases that have the custom field populated. Fortunately, as a new Case, the RefId will be in the `Case.Description` so you can

- Avoid sending out case auto-response rules
- Avoid Case assignment rules from running
- [Merge the new Case](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) with the matching Case using `Database.merge` (do this async)