# Identify component type from ID

Tags: metadata, id

I am curious to know, is there any way exists from where we can know that a particular id is of type VF/class/trigger/components etc.

The way I think/know currently is, to query with "ApexPage" to check whether it is a page, "ApexClass" to check for class.

Is there any single/more prominent way to know this?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Have you read [What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1653/102). I maintain a list of [key prefixes that are common across all orgs](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html).

Comment: @DanielBallinger interesting article indeed... thanks for sharing.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Id.getSObjectType() to know what type an Id is.

```
Id someId = ...;
System.debug(someId.getSObjectType());
```

You can refer to it literally:

```
if(someId.getSobjectType() == ApexClass.sObjectType) {
    // is a apex class
```

Or you check as a string:

```
if(String.someValueOf(someId.getSObjectType()) == 'ApexClass') {
    // is an apex class
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get to know it from the first three digit key prefix whether its a Apex Class, VF Page or Trigger

```
Apex Class - 01p
VF Page - 066
Apex Trigger - 01q
```

Comment: Does these prefix are common across all salesforce orgs? For my org as well, there are same.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to do this such that it is dynamic i.e. works for any component and is reusable. The reusable apex method is available as an official salesforce knowledge article -- [How to find Object Type from Record ID Prefix](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-find-Object-Type-from-Record-ID-Prefix&language=en_US)

Also, it is highly recommended to go through the apex doc for the following methods and understand their return types:

- [Schema.getGlobalDescribe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm)
- [SObjectType.getDescribe()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm#apex_class_Schema_SObjectType)
- [Schema.DescribeSObjectResult.getKeyPrefix()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm%23apex_methods_system_sobject_describe)
- [Schema.DescribeSObjectResult.getName()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm%23apex_methods_system_sobject_describe)

Comment: Searching the entire global describe can easily consume several seconds of CPU time, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the Id type in the following way:

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'account');
insert a;
Id myId = a.id;
System.assertEquals(Schema.Account.SObjectType, myId.getSobjectType());
```

This would work for all sObject Types It would return Class as **ApexClass**, VF Page as **ApexPage** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Small code snippet of how to get all object prefixes in the org.

```
 for ( Schema.SObjectType ot : (Schema.SObjectType[])Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() ) {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dor = ot.getDescribe();
        System.debug('--->>> Prefix: ' + dor.getPrefix() + '; Object: ' + dor.getName() + ';');
    }
```