# What is the value of the first and final record id for an object?

Tags: custom-object, salesforce-id, standard-objects, record

For example, Account IDs have prefix `001` and have `15` alphanumeric digits. What are the values for the **first** and **last** records that can be represented in this format (as we understand Salesforce IDs today)?

Looking at some account ids ordered by `id asc` in my dev org it seems the ordering sorts by 0-9 then a-z then A-Z.

```
0010a00001ACeQl
0010a00001CVCfp
0010a00001CVCfq
0010a00001CVCfr
001j0000003ZS1z
001j0000003ZS20
001j0000003ZS21
001j0000003ZS22
001j0000003ZS23
```

Therefore my guess is the range is between `001000000000000` and `001ZZZZZZZZZZZZ`

Comment: link: [What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of what you need to know is covered in [What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1663/102)

In short, only the last 9 characters of the ID are incremented from record to record.

E.g.

0010a0000000001 to 0010a0ZZZZZZZZZ.

Giving you 62<sup>9</sup> possible identifiers for actual records on a pod for the same org.

The three characters immediately after the keyprefix has other purposes that are detailed in the linked question.

For the ordering, my experience with creating a large number of records in one go has been the following sequence:

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I.e. numbers, upper case, then lower case.

See also:

- [Distance Between Salesforce Ids](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/167750/102) - Converts Base 62 encoded ID to long

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @martin. Yes, it was a lowercase L rather than a 1. Fixed now.