# Why is the Id of the detail page URL different from the Apex context?

Tags: apex, soql, query, id

I have a condition to check the id stored in a custom object; it should match with the user profile id in Apex.

```
CustomObject.ID_Value__c = '00ea0000001p22S'; //I got this from profile detail page url 

Profile p = [select id from profile where name = 'General user Profile' limit 1];

System.debug(CustomObject.ID_Value__c); // 00ea0000001p22S
System.debug(p.ID) // 00ea0000001p22SAAQ extra digits added
```

So how got the condition mismatched? How to overcome this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're the same.

```
system.assertEquals(Id.valueOf('00ea0000001p22SAAQ'), Id.valueOf('00ea0000001p22S'));
```

Salesforce Ids have a 15 digit Id and an 18 digit Id. The longer version is "case-safe" in order to support integrations with a wider array of external systems. For more detail around the conversion from 15 digits to 18 digits, see **[What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of)**

Answer (score 5):

While Adrian's answer is entirely correct that these two values will evaluate as equal as long as at least one of them is an id, I wanted to also point out that in your example, `CustomObject.ID_Value__c` is being displayed in the debug logs without the three-letter suffix because the `ID_Value__c` field is a text field and not a lookup. Consider the following:

```
Account a = new Account();
a.Id = '0019000000PElZu';
a.AccountNumber = '0019000000PElZu';
system.debug(a.Id);                                     // 0019000000PElZuAAL
system.debug(a.AccountNumber);                          // 0019000000PElZu
system.debug(a.Id == a.AccountNumber);                  // true
system.debug(String.valueOf(a.Id) == a.AccountNumber);  // false
```

This happens because, [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm),

> If you set ID to a 15-character value, Apex converts the value to its 18-character representation. All invalid ID values are rejected with a runtime exception.