# UserInfo.getUserId() returns a invalid id

Tags: userinfo

I get the return values as

> <\a href="0054F000002TICN" target="_blank">Abhishek Mendon<\/a>

when I use `UserInfo.getUserId()` to set the a user id for another object.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Any ID that begins with `005` is a user ID. It can be either 15 or 18 characters in length (see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/177680/2984) for the differences between them). Whatever is going on with your problem, this isn't it; the ID is certainly valid.