# What is the best value to use for an Id of a specific SObjectType that matches no records?

Tags: salesforce-id

With reference to the very informative [What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of), I am wondering what the *best value to use for an Id of a **specific SObjectType** that matches nothing* is.

If I understand that link correctly, the Id should be something like:

```
SObjectType t = ...;
Id id = t.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '000' + 'xxxxxxxxx';
```

But what is a good value to use in place of `'xxxxxxxxx'` e.g.:

```
'zzzzzzzzz'
'ZZZZZZZZZ'
'ZzZzZzZzZ'
'000000AAA'
'NoMatchId'
'xxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: I use [fflib_IDGenerator](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks/blob/master/src/classes/fflib_IDGenerator.cls) and it uses 00000000 and each time new Id is generated it keeps a track so next time you ask for new Id it doesnt get repeated

Comment: Hi @PranayJaiswal, Its an Id value that can be thrown into queries and match nothing rather than just a random Id that might match something in the database that I'm looking for. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use all zeroes (e.g. `keyPrefix + '0'.repeat(12)`). It will never match an existing or future ID. Depending on your use case, you can also generally just use `'0'.repeat(15)`, which is what Salesforce uses internally to represent a null ID. Obviously, the 0-key-prefix pattern doesn't match a specific sObject, but might be valid for some use cases. Note that this presumes you're using 15-character ID values. If you calculate the parity bits at the end, remember it may not always be AAA, so consider `Id.valueOf(keyPrefix+'0'.repeat(12))` instead to get the correct suffix.

Comment: The zeroes sound good. I do want to keep the key prefix as down the line code uses the type of the Id. Thanks!