# id value of incorrect type:

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

```
@api guestCodeFromGuestMaster; //getting guest code from parent. Lookup relationship   
@track cardNumber;
@track cardCVV;
@track cardExpiryMonth;
@track cardExpiryYear;



createPaymentRecord() {
        const fields = { 'Payer_Details__c': this.guestCodeFromGuestMaster, 'Card_Number__c': this.cardNumber, 'CVV__c': this.cardCVV, 'Expiry_Month__c': this.cardExpiryMonth, 'Expiry_Year__c': this.cardExpiryYear };
    
    const recordInput = { apiName: 'Payment_Master__c', fields };
    createRecord(recordInput).then(response => {
        console.log('Payment record has been created', response.id);
        this.recordId = response.id;
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Payment Record saved',
            message: 'Record Saved Successfully',
            variant: 'success',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
        this.sendEmailAfterEvent();
        this.navigateToRecordPage();
        
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('error in creating payment record ', error.message.body);
    });

 }
```

It's throwing error as below:

```
errorCode: "MALFORMED_ID"
field: "Payer_Details__c"
fieldLabel: "Payer Details"
message: "Payer Details: id value of incorrect type: GC-292"
```

[image]

because of this record is not getting saved. If I'm removing this field(Payer_Details__c) then record is getting saved.

Please let me know what should I do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get this Malformed ID exception when you try to update the parent recordID on a child record.
Here you are not passing the SF 18digit record ID in that field. As per the error you are trying to update the field value as GC-292 instead of passing the 15/18 char record ID.
Instead of getting the recordName from the Calling component, try to pass the recordId.
If you can't get the recordId then replace the recordName with the recordId on the apex side by querying for the record Id just before using the dml update statement in your apex code.

Comment: Thank you Naveen. It worked. I passed record Id.

Answer (score 1):

The data you pass to the "guestCodeFromGuestMaster" variable doesn't have an [Id format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of).
You have 2 options here:

1. Make sure that you pass the real Id value
2. If you need to match the record using "GC-292" value, then you need to populate a field that has "External Id" option enabled.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I passed record Id and it's working now.