# How to verify if a string is a Salesforce ID on LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce-id

I know we have a couple of options on the Apex side, but I would like to do that verification without calling the server, is there another option direct on the LWC side?

FYI: I used to use the [Id class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_Id_valueOf) valueOf(toID) and verify if the return is not an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the ID is a valid ID, you would have no way of knowing if it's a valid ID without calling Apex or a query. This [old answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1663/2984) goes into the format of an Id; the basic idea is that you can check for a 15 character string of only letters and numbers, and an optional three-character ending that encodes the uppercase-ness of the first 15 characters. Beyond that, calling the server is required to see if the ID is valid for the current user.