# System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

Tags: apex, compile-error, calendar

I am a newbie to Apex programming in Salesforce so I have been basing my code off of the example code found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_calendarview.htm

With slight modifications to the Start/End/Display fields, and the object type as well as filters - the CalendarView object is helpful to my organization.

I am trying to programmatically create and distribute a calendar to all of my users with these settings:
[image: object calendar lightning experience]

Here is the code I am using:

```
/*Changelog: 
*1/5/23 Intial Release
*1/6/23 Modified Class name to prevent compiler error
*/

public class ServiceSchedule
{

/*Setup method for creation/assignment of calendars*/

public static void getCalendar()
{
    Group userGroup = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Service' LIMIT 1];
    List<Id> groupId = new List<Id>();
    groupId.add(userGroup.id);
    List<GroupMember> groupMembers = [SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN: groupId];
    
    List<CalendarView> calendarViews = new List<CalendarView>();
    for (GroupMember groupMember : groupMembers) 
    {
       CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(name = 'Field Service Schedule', SobjectType = 'Case', 
           StartField = 'Service_Visit_Start__c', EndField = 'Service_Visit_End__c', 
           DisplayField = 'Subject', ListViewFilterId = '00B5w00000FytcOEAR', OwnerId = groupMember.UserOrGroupId);
       calendarViews.add(calendarView);
    }
    insert calendarViews;
}

}
```

When I open an 'anonymous debugging session' I run the command "ServiceSchedule.getCalendar();"

and this is the error message I get:

```
    Line: 26, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
```

From what I can understand the error message is saying that it can't run the "insert calendarViews" command because of something wrong with the ID? I am getting the ID from the sample code in the documentation and I am not modifying it at all. Could that be my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting the ID from the sample code in the documentation and I am not modifying it at all. Could that be my issue?

Yes, that is 100% the issue.

Hard-coding Ids is bad practice. This is because Ids are pretty much guaranteed to be different when you run in (or are deploying to) a different org. The one exception to that is when you create or refresh a full-copy sandbox (also possible in a partial-copy sandbox). In that situation, the Id(s) in the sandbox will match the Id(s) in production.

Instead of doing that, you should query the `ListView` object (outside of your loop, queries inside of loops are practically always a terrible idea because we're limited to 100 queries in a single, sychronous transaction). Using the developer name is generally preferred because those need to be unique across your org.

Something like `Listview myListview = [SELECT Id FROM Listview WHERE DeveloperName = 'Some name here'];`
Do also note that SOQL queries return a `List<SObject>`. Salesforce allows us to assign the result of a query to a single instance when the query returns *exactly one row*. Trying to do this will result in an error if your query either returns 0 rows, or 2+ rows.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Just for my own clarity, are you suggesting to remove this section of code: Group userGroup = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Service' LIMIT 1];

And replace it with something "new" that is a Listview instead? 

I am not fimilar with that a DeveloperName is in this context. I am assuming that is the 'real' name and not the ID that is randomly generated Hex String?

Comment: @CDutko Not quite, it's the `ListViewFilterId = '00B5w00000FytcOEAR'` bit that is problematic. You'll want to query for the listview and then use that object's Id, much like you're currently doing with `userGroup`. I.e. your code should be `ListViewFilterId = myListView.Id`. DeveloperName (also called the "api name" in some locations" is similar to the `Name` (i.e. the label), just with spaces and special characters replaced with underscores (e.g. "Non-Recurring Revenue" would be "Non_Recurring_Revenue")

Comment: I wish it was possible to give out rep! Your help has been extraordinary. Thank you so much (:

Comment: @CDutko Also, Salesforce Ids are base-62 (not base-64) and not hex. [This question goes into more detail about Salesforce Ids](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of). You'll also be able to upvote once you hit 15 rep yourself. Accepting an answer gives me 15 rep (and you 2 rep).