# Any tips on how to copy an Account Id into a custom text field on Account record create?

Tags: trigger

Our App syncs to Salesforce objects using a Listing ID field that matches Account or Opportunity or Case Number but the field needs to be set to an External ID and those number fields do not allow that.  So,

We added a custom field to Account record that we configured to operate as External ID
And we want the value in that field to be copied from the 18 digit Account Id

We've tried adding a trigger to

```java
trigger CopyAccountNumberToCustomField on Account (before insert) {
    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        // Check if Account Number is not null or empty
        if (String.isNotBlank(acc.AccountNumber)) {
            acc.Listing_ID__c = acc.AccountNumber; // Copy Account Number to Listing_ID custom field
        }
    }
}
```

And we tried adding a trigger after insert

```java
trigger CopyAccountNumberToCustomField on Account (after update) {
    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        // Check if Account Number is not null or empty
        if (String.isNotBlank(acc.AccountNumber)) {
            acc.Listing_ID__c = acc.AccountNumber; // Copy Account Number to Listing_ID custom field
        }
    }
}
```

neither one worked

Any tips on how to copy an Account Number into a custom text field on Account record create?

Comment: In your second trigger example, is the `after update` a typo, or do you really have it as `after update` and not `after insert`?

Comment: I've tried it with both ``after update`` and ``after insert``  neither one works.

Comment: Are you explicitly populating `AccountNumber` in whatever code/process you're using to create Accounts? `AccountNumber` is not an auto-number field, so it will be null (blank) unless you populate it.

Comment: We're trying to get the 18 digit Salesforce ID... what is that field called?

Comment: thank you sir.  much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

Every object in Salesforce has an Id field which stores a unique reference for each record of that object. This can be used as an external Id by external systems. You do not need to copy it to another field in a trigger.

The API name for this field on every object is `Id`. So if you did want to copy it to another field, you would do:

```
acc.Listing_Id__c = acc.Id;
```

For more information about Ids, see here: [Locate the Unique ID of a Record in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385008&type=1)

And for a really detailed description of how they are formed: [What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of)